# Is there a word for singing in a way that denotes utter desperation, anguish, or otherwise being at one's emotional edge?

Tags: single-word-requests

Chantepleure means "singing and weeping (or crying) simultaneously;" I am looking for something similar but that does not require actual tears, actual crying (just the same degree of emotional intensity either throughout, or more common, in the tail-end of a song). Some examples of what I mean would be:

Prince - Beautiful Ones: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKZYpcetFVg [From 3:10 to 4:30]

Leona Lewis - Run - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pelOvxFuJj8 [from 3:10 to 4:10]

Michael Jackson - Earth Song - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OstvvP8QuxQ [From 4:10 to end]

To a lesser degree:

Hurt - Christina Aguilera - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=___l8Y21yNM [an example where the entire song has that style to a degree but especially the latter half]....

Say Something (I'm giving up on you) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BmErRm-vApI - is another song that, throughout, exhibits a real degree or extent of the emotions / emotionalism in view.

The style seems more common in soul, pop, rock, and related musical forms. The words crescendo and climax are close but numerous songs have a crescendo/climax portion that doesn't reach the level of emotional intensity, sadness, desperation, etc. that these songs (and many others) convey.

Comment: In screamo, the emotional climax of a song is called a meltdown.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Not sure if that is limited to screamo (not familiar with the genre) or if it is a term that fits across the board but, in many songs that I have in view, "meltdown" would describe the intensity involved. Thanks for your response!

Comment: @M.Wildy A dirge, played at a funeral.

Comment: *chantepleure* is a very beautiful word. I don't see a problem metaphorically extending it  to describe emotional songs like Aguilera's Hurt or any song by Adelle.

Answer (score 2):

The crowd felt the emotion of the moment when the the team's captain sang a moving **lament** in honor of their deceased teammate.

**Lament:** To feel, show, or express grief, sorrow or regret; a formal expression of sorrow or mourning , especially in verse or song. (Dictionary.com)

Answer (score 1):

***Keening***

To wail in grief (for a dead person); sing a keen; to make an eerie wailing sound.

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=the%20sound%20the%20wind%20makes%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#newwindow=1&q=KEENING)